# Browsing through Dictionary in OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, dictionary

Is there any way to browse through Apple's dictionary without searching word for word?
I guess it's not that important since I can just type "a" in the search field and just go through all the words beginning with A and so on, but I'm curious to know whether there is an actual way to go through all the words, one at a time.